# Angularjs $http.get service not returning data to calling controller function

Tags: angularjs, service, controller

Hi Everyone I'm sure there is a simple solution to this problem but I can't seem to find it myself...

I have a controller that assigns data to the $scope.items variable by calling a service defined as GetDataService

```
$scope.items = GetDataService.getData('/getBroadcastSourceList/1');
```

The service is set up as follows:

```
angular.module('appName')
  .service('GetDataService', function($http, WebServiceURL) {
    this.getData = function(ServiceParameter) {
      $http.get(WebServiceURL + ServiceParameter)
        .then(function(res){
          return res.data;
        });
    };
  });
```

I have stepped through my code in the GetDataService and can see that res.data does contain all relevant data however this data is not sent to $scope.items in my controller.

I have also checked that all is well on my controller side by changing my service as follows:

```
angular.module('appName')
      .service('GetDataService', function($http, WebServiceURL) {
        this.getData = function(ServiceParameter) {
           return [{
                     Day: "Monday",
                     Language: "English "
                   }]
        };
      });
```

This does populate $scope.items so the issue must be somewhere here:

```
$http.get(WebServiceURL + ServiceParameter)
        .then(function(res){
          return res.data;
        });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$http service is aync in nature so you need to assign data in a callback

```
GetDataService.getData('/getBroadcastSourceList/1').then(function(data) {
  $scope.items=data;
})
```

Also your service does not have a `return`, add it.

```
this.getData = function(ServiceParameter) {
      return $http.get(WebServiceURL + ServiceParameter)
```

Comment: OP not returning `$http` to do that

Comment: Thanks for this it works except the object that gets returned consists of .config, .data and .headers. How do I only return the data part and not the other stuff?

Comment: But right now $scope.items = data.data; gets me what I want

Comment: If you keep the `then` in place, you would not have to do `data.data`

Answer (score 0):

You are not retuning nothing on the getData method of your service try to return a promise

```
angular.module('appName')
  .service('GetDataService', function($http, $q WebServiceURL) {
    this.getData = function(ServiceParameter) {
var defer = $q.defer();
      $http.get(WebServiceURL + ServiceParameter)
        .then(function(res){
         defer.resolve(res.data);
        }, function (err) { defer.reject(err)});
return defer.promise;
    };
```

Comment: yep you can return the promise from $http anyway